# Different columns for sections in a table-like layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there an existing layout in android where I can do the following:

*header*
| A  | BB  | CC  |
| A  | BB  | CC  |
*header*
| AAA   | B  | C |
| AAA   | B  | C |
*header*
| A | B | C | D |
| A | B | C | D |

I mean, different column widths and/or wifferent columns count for each section (headers could be hand made out of modified rows, but if there's any way of achieving this too it would be excellent).

I'm trying to reproduce something I did in iOS, but I only know the basics of android. Here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ll8grj59eiukqh5/list.png) of the desired result.

I think I could do it with linear layouts and a lot of custom logic, but I'm hoping there's a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like three different [GridViews](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) would be appropriate for this kind of layout. You could add your own custom TextViews as headers to each.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! but the thing is I need a fully flexible layout that can have any number of columns in each section (and with the best widths according to its contents) and be prepared to have any number of sections (30 or more). Is there any chance?

Comment: For any number of columns, you could try playing with android:numColumns="autofit" and android:stretchMode="columnWidth". If you added each GridView in code then you could account for as many sections as you need, too.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but I have many troubles adapting my custom content (see update above). I think autofit doesn't work, it always shows 2 columns, so I'm setting numcolumns programmatically. Plus, android:stretchMode="columnWidth" makes all columns the same width, and other modes don't show any content. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You can try to set different column widths using code like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6657410/475217. And the stretchMode property can be used to allow stretching in different areas...perhaps one of these others could help: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:stretchMode You have a fairly complex layout, so I don't know if there is an easy solution.